# Michael Hartl chapter 8.3 logging out sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, logout, railstutorial.org

I'm going through Michael Hartl's *The Ruby on Rails Tutorial, Chapter 8.3 Logging Out Sessions* and I don't understand how removing the `session[:user_id]` can remove the `@current_user` as well:

here is the SessionController:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new

  end

  def create
    user =User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in(user)
      redirect_to user
    else
      #flash.now will only flash once - if a new request or view is rendered,the flash will go away now
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end

  end

  def destroy

    log_out
    redirect_to root_path

  end

end
```

and here is the SessionsHelper for the login and logout helpers:

```
module SessionsHelper

    def log_in(user)

        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end

    def current_user
        #find the user if @user is not defined yet, or else, just keep the current user
        #that way we dont have to do a database search every time current_user is called
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    end

    def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?

    end
    def log_out
        session.delete(:user_id)
    end
end
```

The way I understand, once `@current_user` is defined once logged in, shouldn't the variable still last even though the `session[:user_id]` has been removed since it is being set to itself?

```
@current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
```

There was no action that I am aware of that removed the `@current_user` variable. But when I tested it during the debugger, I can see that once someone logs out, `@current_user` becomes `nil`.

Can someone explain the mechanics to me?

Answer (score 1):

The [session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) persists between requests.  But the instance variable `@current_user` only persists for the length of one request.  When the `destroy` action redirects to the `root_path` that is the start of a new request which will load the root page.

You may want to try this out so see that clearing the `user_id` out of the session doesn't clear out the instance variable:

```
def destroy
  # Test code to initialize @current_user
  current_user
  Rails.logger.debug("@current_user before: #{@current_user.inspect}")

  log_out

  # Test code to check @current_user after updating session
  Rails.logger.debug("@current_user after: #{@current_user.inspect}")

  redirect_to root_path
end
```

And then check what ends up in `log/development.log`.  `@current_user` will still be present after `log_out` but it will go away at the end of the request.

Comment: Thanks that's useful! However, I tried this:
>def destroy
>Rails.logger.debug("@current_user value: #{@current_user.inspect}")
log_out
>Rails.logger.debug("@current_user value: #{@current_user.inspect}")
redirect_to root_path
end
>but I am getting that the @current_user is nil on both counts:
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
Parameters:{"authenticity_token"=>"OjnBcB5CAdUbuGmW68lzlkVqx8B3R7f+6ZTdUGBj61XC/vuFa9Vp7oAodT6RtkFNVTduPgp0hB5UaMVStJIjGg=="}
>@current_user value: nil
>@current_user value: nil
looks like current_user was never set?

Comment: Sorry, you're right about that.  I've updated the example in my answer.  The `destroy` action didn't need to know the current user so it never set it.  Any request that needs the current user calls  the `current_user` helper method and `@current_user` exists from then on until the end of the request.

Comment: Ok I see thanks! One more follow up question - So, in my _header.html.erb partial I used this: `<li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>` Which, should have set @current_user, right? So why do I need to call current_user again in the controller for it to be set?

Comment: The two common options when a controller [creates a response](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#creating-responses) are to either render or redirect.  The `detroy` action didn't render.  Instead it just redirected to the root path.  So the code in `_header.html.erb` was not executed by `destroy`.  If you look for the "Rendered" references in `log/development.log` you can see which templates are rendered by a given controller action.